# Zoom on y-axis while using plotly::rangeslider

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I would like to zoom in on the y-axis on a plotly plot that uses `rangeslider`.

A reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
p <- ggplot(faithful, aes(x = waiting)) +
    geom_histogram(bins = 30)
p <- ggplotly(p)
p <- rangeslider(p)
p
```

The way I can zoom is the following:

[image]

However, I would like to be able to also zoom like this (which is done by not adding a `rangeslider`):

[image]

I assume this can be done by using something along the lines of

```
p <- layout(p, dragmode = "zoom")
```

but I haven't been able to make this work.

Comment: ```p <- rangeslider(p, start = min(floor(p$x$data[[1]]$x))-1, end = max(ceiling(p$x$data[[1]]$x))+1) %>% layout(p, yaxis = list(fixedrange = FALSE))``` this works too. Notice that you need to specify `start` and `end` if you are setting up `rangeslider` outside of `layout`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In reference to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/2364), it can be done by setting `fixedrange` to `FALSE` for `yaxis`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

ggplot(faithful, aes(x = waiting)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 30) -> p

ggplotly(p) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(rangeslider = list()),
         yaxis = list(fixedrange = FALSE)) -> p
```

[image]

Comment: This does exactly what I want and it also fixes the issue of the rangeslider having weird default start and end values (which I wasn't able to fix setting ```end = max(data$x)```). Thanks!

Comment: Amazingly simple answer, this will override the Plotly defaults when using rangeslider, even for subplots.